# Loop through XML String using XPath - Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a function I would like to loop through the xml and pull out certain tags.

My xml looks like this:

```
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Company>Test</Company>
        <Name>Test Name</Name>
        <Division>Test Division</Division>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Company>Test 2</Company>
        <Name>Test Name 2</Name>
        <Division>Test Division 2</Division>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Company>Test 3</Company>
        <Name>Test Name 3</Name>
        <Division>Test Division 3</Division>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Here is my code to loop through:

```
String comp, name, div, nodeName, NodeValue;
Node node;
try
{
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(coaFULL));
Document doc2 = (Document) xpath.evaluate("/", source, XPathConstants.NODE);

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile("/Report_Data/Report_Entry").evaluate(doc2, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println("NODE LIST LENGTH =" + nodeList.getLength());

String nodeName, nodeValue = "";
Node node;

for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
{
    node = nodeList.item(i);
    node = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild();
    nodeName = node.getNodeName();
    nodeValue = node.getChildNodes().item( 0 ).getNodeValue();

    if(nodeName.equals("Company"))
    {
        comp = nodeValue;
    }
    else if( nodeName.equals("Name"))
    {
        name = nodeValue;
    }
    else if(nodeName.equals("Division"))
    {
        div = nodeValue;
    }
    System.out.println("COMPANY = " + comp);
    System.out.println("NAME = " + name);
    System.out.println("DIVISION = " + div);
}
```

When I run my code, only the first value (company) gets an actual value, everything else is blank. I also tried adding `node = nodeList.item(i).getNextSibling();` inside of each if statement to grab the next node, but that did not work.

My nodeList does have items in it, over 1000.  Is there a problem with this statement: `NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile("/Report_Data/Report_Entry").evaluate(doc2, XPathConstants.NODESET);`?

Should it be: `NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile("/Report_Data/Report_Entry/*").evaluate(doc2, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

I tried it with the `/*` at the end but that caused the nodeList to have every single node in it.  I want to make sure that when I grab a Report_Entry node, that I set the string variables to the correct values that correspond to each other.

==========================================================

Solution: It's ugly but my solution was to just go with one loop and use the second list of children nodes with hard coded values:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
{
    node = nodeList.item(i);
    tempList = node.getChildNodes();
    System.out.println("TEMP LIST LENGTH =" + tempList.getLength());
    comp = tempList.item(0).getTextContent();
    name = tempList.item(1).getTextContent();
    div = tempList.item(2).getTextContent();
}
```

Thanks to @hage for his help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because your `node` is only the first child?

```
node = nodeList.item(i);
node = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild();
```

I guess `nodeList.item(i)` will give you the `Report_Entry`s and their first child is the `Company`.

You will need to loop over all children of the `Company` entry

**EDIT** (regarding your edit):

`tempList.item(x)` is the `Company`, `Name`, and then `Division`. When you get the first child of this one, you are at the text node (the actual content). And because you try to get the name of this node, you get the `#text` output ([see this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/xpath/package-tree.html)).

To get name and value of the nodes, try this (untested)

```
nodeName = tempList.item(x).getNodeName();
nodeValue = tempList.item(x).getTextContent();
```